# How to run CasperJS from cron inside AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, casperjs

I am having difficulties running my CasperJS script as a cron job on my AWS EC2 server.

**The crontab:**

```
0 13 * * * PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/ec2-user/local/bin/phantomjs /home/ec2-user/local/bin/casperjs /home/ec2-user/code/scraptest.js
```

The script runs fine when I run it manually but cron emails me with the following:

```
(...)
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=ec2-user>

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I've tried everything I could think of and I am running out of ideas. Any advice?

Comment: what is the OS of this EC2 ?

Comment: The OS of the EC2 is Linux!

Comment: Linux is too wide. Specify !

Comment: Here you go: Linux version 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64010) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 2 04:38:47 UTC 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've finally found a solution to my problem: I added the environment variables into the command line. In my case:

```
55 08 * * * env - PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/ec2-user/local/bin" /home/ec2-user/local/bin/casperjs /home/ec2-user/code/scraptest.js
```

Answer (score 0):

cron and your session do not share the environment variables, it looks like you discovered that.

Frankly there is a much better way to deal with this, and that is to define your PATH and other ENV vars globally within your crontab, that way if you add another cron entry you're not writing your ENV into every command!

Your cron will work fine this this, plus you can add a MAILTO= and get cron to e-mail most any address any errors or STDOUT you want

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/ec2-user/local/bin"

55 08 * * * /home/ec2-user/local/bin/casperjs /home/ec2-user/code/scraptest.js
```